# Java loop run only for the max tries

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, do-loops

I have created an if statement while it's true to keep on asking question until you get it right. However that is not an option in my case. I have implemented a counter with the max tries, if the loop runs 3 times and you still got it wrong then print "you got it wrong" and go to the next question. If they get it right within 3 tries, "go to the next question" the score++ is just there to keep track of the score. score++ must keep the score only for the correct answer that is why its under while (true). If someone could help me out, that would be awesome. I am open to different ways I can improve my loop.
Thank you!

Here's the loop:

```
int count = 0;
int maxTries = 3;

do {
    println(q1.PrintQuestion());
    yourAnswer = readLine("Your answer: ");
    if ((q1.IsAnswerCorrect(yourAnswer)) && (count < maxTries))
        break;
    else
        println("You got it wrong! \n");
        count++;
} while (true);

score++; 
println("You got it right! \n");
```

Edit:
Here is the working loop I have thanks to the answers here. Now the problem I'm having is if the answer is correct it does not go to the next question until I answer it correctly two times and if I have maxTries set to 3 it goes 4 times that is why I decreased to 2 times. with the last max try if I input correctly, I have to answer it twice.

```
    int count = 0;
    int maxTries = 2;

    do {
        println(q1.PrintQuestion());
        yourAnswer = readLine("Your answer: ");
        if ((q1.IsAnswerCorrect(yourAnswer)) || (count >= maxTries))
        break;
        else
            println("You got it wrong! \n");
            count++;

    } while (true);

    score++; 
    println("You got it right! \n");
```

Comment: In this instance `do { ... } while(true);` and `while(true) { ... }` are the same. The latter's use would be more beneficial to others who might need to read your code. On a related subject, using a `boolean` variable instead of `while(true) { if(...) { break; } }` would benefit you when needing to update this code in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The count needs to be incremented inside tho loop rather than outside. Also your condition for checking if maxtries are reached or the correct answer is provided is incorrect:

```
if ((q1.IsAnswerCorrect(yourAnswer)) || (count >= maxTries))
    break;
else
    println("You got it wrong! \n");
    count++;
```

Will stop when the correct answer is provided or when `maxTries` is reached.

Comment: Thanks, that worked but for whatever reason it works after 5 tries even thought the int is for maxTries is set to 3. Wondering what could the problem be.

Comment: @Dmirtriy Move `count++` to the start of your loop. As I have it written above the count only goes up after you check if they have reached the maximum number of tries.

Answer (score 0):

You should increment `count` within the `while` loop. Then your code can detect whether the maximum number of tries has been reached.

You also (presumably) need to exit the loop once the maximum number of tries has been reached. Otherwise, you'll get a loop you cannot break out of. That is, once the max tries is reached, even if the answer is correct, the loop will not exit.

If you leave increment score outside the while loop it will add to the score in both cases, ie. the answer was right or the number of tries was used up. It should probably go inside the loop too.

```
int count = 0;
int maxTries = 3;

do {
    println(q1.PrintQuestion());
    yourAnswer = readLine("Your answer: ");
    if (q1.IsAnswerCorrect(yourAnswer)) {
        println("You got it right!\n");
        score++;
        break;
    } 
    println("You got it wrong!\n");
    count++;
    if (count > maxtries) {
        println("You ran out of tries.\n");
        break;
    }
} while (true);
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't really understand your statement. It was after while true, I moved it under else "count++;" same results

Comment: this statement worked but after I replaced && (count < maxTries) with || (count >= maxTries)

Answer (score 0):

Your count++ needs to be inside the loop. Otherwise your condition (count < maxTries) is on use, because count++ will never increment while your loop is running.

```
int count = 0;
int maxTries = 3;

do {
    println(q1.PrintQuestion());
    yourAnswer = readLine("Your answer: ");
    if ((q1.IsAnswerCorrect(yourAnswer)) && (count < maxTries)) {
        break;
    }
    else {
        println("You got it wrong! \n");
    }
    //count++ inside the loop
    count++;
} while (true);
score++; 
println("You got it right! \n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting your score++ and count++ line inside your loop.

Comment: the reason I have score++ outside of loop to keep track if the answer was ever answered correct. I fixed the count++ inside the loop.